# How to generate a report in excel (xls, xlsx) format on ODOO?

Tags: excel, report, odoo-10, odoo, odoo-view

In purchase module, I want to generate the details which is being printed in the purchase order button as a pdf report. My requirement is how to print the report in excel format in odoo 10?

Answer (score 7):

You can export the current tree view as an excel file with this module: [`web_export_view`](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/web_export_view/)

Or you can build your own excel report with this other modules: [`report_xls`](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/report_xls/) [`report_xlsx`](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/report_xlsx/)

There are modules that already use the `report_xls` module, but you can look for them in the Odoo Apps or in the OCA repository