# Generate XLSX(Excel) report in odoo 10 from custom module?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm using odoo 10 i created qweb report for `stock.production.lot` module and i want to create the same report in XLSX format.

How can i create XLSX report in odoo 10 for `stock.ptoduction.lot`

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of data is related to this question likewise:

1) An app is there for this:

[Free app in odoo app store for xlsx report generation](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/report_xlsx/)

2) One blog is there for this:

[Blog on report generation](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-create-a-xls-report-in-odoo)

3) Stack question is there:

[Stackoverflow question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263354/how-to-generate-a-report-in-excel-xls-xlsx-format-on-odoo)

From this you can easily able to get answer of your question.